# React setState changes the value of all objects in different state variable

Tags: reactjs, arrays, setstate

Here's my code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";


export default function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("")
  const [list, setList] = useState([
    {key:584535, value:"Do laundry", isChecked: false},
    {key:439735, value:"Take out trash", isChecked: false},
    {key:589774, value:"Do dishes", isChecked: true},
    {key:573735, value:"code", isChecked: false},
    {key:589739, value:"margin", isChecked: false},
    {key:585735, value:"textbox", isChecked: false}]
    )
  const [history, setHistory] = useState([[]])
  function handleCheckClick(e) {    
    let checkkey = e.target.getAttribute("checkboxkey")
    setHistory([...history, list])
    list.map(
      (element) => {
        if(element.key == checkkey){
          element.isChecked = !(element.isChecked)
        }
      }
    )
    setList([...list])
  }
  function handleRemoveClick(e) {
    let buttonKey = e.target.getAttribute("buttonkey") 
    list.forEach(
      (element, index) => {
        if(element.key == buttonKey){
          setHistory([...history, list])
          setList(list.toSpliced(index, 1))
        }
      }
    )
  }
  function handleSubmit() {
    if(input == ""){return}
    let key = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000)
      setHistory([...history, list])
      setList([...list, {key: key, value: input, isChecked:false}]) 
      setInput("")
  }
  function handleHistoryClick(){
    if((history[history.length-1]) == undefined){return}
    setList(history.pop())
    setHistory([...history])
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>To Do</h1>
      <input id="input" type="text" value={input} onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}></input>
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
      <button onClick={handleHistoryClick}>Undo</button>
      <div id="container">
        <ol>
          {list.map(({key, value, isChecked}) =>
            <>
              {isChecked === true && <li id="strike" key={key}>{value}</li>}
              {isChecked === false && <li key={key}>{value}</li>}
              <input type="checkbox" checkboxkey={key} onClick={handleCheckClick}></input>
              <button buttonkey={key} onClick={handleRemoveClick}>Remove</button>
              <br />
           </>)
          }
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have a history array which saves copies of all changes made to the main list array. When I'm trying to resign the isClicked value to the main array with `element.isChecked = !(element.isChecked)` in list.map, it changes the value in all the history arrays! Here is am image of the console when I console.log history every time I toggle the checkbox with the "textbox" value, the last click was to set it to clicked: [Console.log of history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygK2I.png)

Comment: When you place an object from one array into another, each array holds a reference to the same object. Which means that if you change it in any of the arrays, it changes in both. Same thing, in plain codespeak: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/efst19g2/

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

Objects in JavaScript are *references*.  So when two arrays reference the same object(s), mutating an object in one array will affect the object in the other array.  Because for any given instance there's only *one* object, it's just being referenced by more than one array/variable/etc.

Given that this is React code, the simple lesson here is *don't mutate state in React*.  Which is what this line of code is doing:

```
element.isChecked = !(element.isChecked)
```

(Additionally, this is a misuse of the `.map()` function where logically a `.forEach()` or a loop would be more appropriate.  `.map()` is used for projecting a collection into a new collection of the same size, not as a drop-in replacement for simply iterating to perform an operation.)

Instead, project the array into a new array of new objects when updating state.  For example:

```
setHistory([...history, list]);
setList(list.map(
  (element) => {
    if(element.key == checkkey) {
      return { ...element, isChecked = !element.isChecked };
    } else {
      return element;
    }
  }
));
```

The key difference here is what the callback to `.map()` returns.  If the "key" matches, it returns a new object built from the existing object plus one modified property.  Else, it returns the object as-is.  So any object which needs to change results in a new object, rather than mutating the existing one.